# Property inside derived class is null, but not in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have this simple class:

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    private string _file;
    private int _bytesSent;

    public MyFileInfo(string file)
    {

    }

    public string File
    {
        get { return _file; }
        set { _file = value; }
    }

    public int BytesSent
    {
        get { return _bytesSent; }
        set { _bytesSent= value; }
    }
}
```

Additionally, here is the derive class:

```
public class MyFile : MyFileInfo
{
    public MyFile(MyFileInfo myFileInfo)
    {

    }

    public DoWork()
    {
        // File is null 
    }
}
```

The derive class received the base class in the `constructor` and inside my `DoWork` method the `property` File is `null` although in the `constructor` it not null.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why are you passing an object of the base class in the constructor in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

You're not saving the value assigned to the constructor parameter anywhere:

```
public MyFileInfo(string file)
{
    _file = file;
}
```

Depending on how you instantiate, call and intend to use the derived class, you also need to pass the parameter to the base constructor:

```
public MyFile(MyFileInfo myFileInfo)
    : base(myFileInfo.File)
{
}
```

Comment: And if i have several properties inside my base class i need to wtite it this way: : base(myFileInfo.Property1, myFileInfo.Property2,..)

Comment: Depends on what the base constructor looks like and what values you want to pass down.

Comment: All the properties from the base class i want to pass to the derive class

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you pass base class, does not necessary mean you use values of that class. You *at least* need to do something like:

```
public MyFile(MyFileInfo myFileInfo)
{
    this.File = myFileInfo.File;
}
```